# MVC - saving a value from a dropdown list to a field in the database

Tags: model-view-controller

Hi, I have created a small application that has two tables .

```
        Product table 

        ProductID int 
        ProductName string
        BrandID int

        Brands
        BrandId int
        BrandName string
```

I have managed to get the list of brand names to appear in a dropdown list box on the edit view
and the correct Brand name is selected in it when I run the details view.
However if I change nothing and press save I get the following error
          [image: Error Message]

Do I have retrieve the value that was selected in the dropdown and manually assign it or is there a simplier way ?

I am using entity framework

Populating the brandlist when getting the Edit page

public Products Get(int id)
              {
                Products product =  db.Products.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ProductID == id);
                if (product != null)
                {
                 product.Brandlist = db.Brands.ToList();
                 }
                  return product;
              }

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks 
Rachael

View Page

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BrandID, new SelectList(Model.Brandlist, "BrandID", "BrandName"), "- Select a Brand -")

Comment: assuming you are saving information in
 ProductID int        
 ProductName string
 BrandID int

since your BrandID cannot be NULL in this scenario. If brandlist is a manadory field set it as required else change your model to

ProductID int 
ProductName string
BrandID int?

Comment: Thanks Nick. I think the problem is that the brandid in the product table is not getting populated from what is selected in the dropdown box, and thats what i am stuck it. Its is selecting the right brand that is already saved to the product but not assigning it back on save